# Defining all the HTML in React app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Right now I have only one html element `<div id="container"></div>` and all my HTML code in a React app like this

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='navbar navbar-dark'>
          ..
        </div>
        <div className='container'>
          ..
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Is this really the way to do it? Only my menu and content are dynamic.

For instance, I have the menu

```
<Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>Brand</Link>
<ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
  <li className='nav-item'><IndexLink className='nav-link' to='/' activeClassName='active'>Home</IndexLink></li>
  <li className='nav-item'><NavLink className='nav-link' to='/contact'>Contact</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

which has to be defined in React, and the content

```
<div className='container'>
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

which also has to be defined in React.

But all the other html is not dynamic, so should I also define this in React or is it better to have a normal html document in which I replace only the menu and the content, and then keep the rest as normal html?

Answer (score 0):

All of your `app` html will be static, but rendered with the virtual DOM.

Since your nav and content most likely will run off of some routing mechanism, they probably should be located in the same application.

You could write your `app` component inside a more static function like this to remove the extra weight of the lifecycle methods, as an option:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div className='navbar navbar-dark'>
      ..
    </div>
    <div className='container'>
      ..
    </div>
  </div>
);
```